# How to Move a Line Up or Down in Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm familiar with how to move a line up or down in other editors, like Atom and Sublime.

How is this done in Visual Studio Code for Mac?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code for Mac...

> To move a line **UP**: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (alt + up arrow key)
>
> To move a line **DOWN**: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (alt + down arrow key)

See here for a reference on [Basic Editing Key Bindings in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing).

Comment: Works for Windows 10

Comment: Note that you have to disable mac's default keyboard shortcuts for Mission Control for this to work on Catalina

Comment: for me it always moves up/down by 2 lines (macOS)

Comment: This did not work on my Mac. But the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107245/1506477 worked

Answer (score 62):

For Windows:

- To move a line UP: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (alt + up arrow key)
- To move a line DOWN:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (alt + down arrow key)

Comment: And Linux too :)

Comment: MacOS: option + ⬆️

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio Code for Mac for me it is:

> To move a line **UP**: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (alt + shift + up arrow keys)
>
> To move a line **DOWN**: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (alt + shift + arrow down keys)

I do have [IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) installed.

Comment: This shifts the code up and down, however also duplicates the code as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the corresponding commands in the *Selection* menu (*Move Line Up* and *Move Line Down*) together with currently set short-cuts.

Additionally, if you launch the command palette (*View/ Command Palette*) while you have an open document you also find them there (type "move" or "line").

Comment: This answer could be better if you add the keys too.

Comment: Keys can be customised. I'm just teaching how to fish. 

Comment: I see it different now—the tao of programming. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for `Visual Studio` (2019) on Windows and found yourself here, the default keyboard shortcut is the same as for `Visual Studio Code` as shown by @tapu74.

- Move line up = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>
- Move line down = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

To change the shortcuts, say to match `Notepad++` where the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>:

- Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
- In `Show commands containing` enter `Edit.MoveSelected`
- Change `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp` or `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown` as required

Answer (score 1):

FOR VS CODE MAC:

opt + UP, opt + DOWN

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to move the selected lines down but couldn't move it. I can easily move the line up. Then I realised that I needed to create more lines downwards as I was trying to move the code to undefined area. First create some lines by pressing enter.