# How to make VS Code's "Move Line Up" (or down) feature auto-apply appropriate indentation like Atom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I have some xml like this:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>
            Bad indentation here
    </bar>
</foo>
```

You might not be able to tell, but the *bad* line is indented with tabs (3 of them), whereas the other lines are indented with spaces (3 of them). Frankly, that part doesn't matter -- just understand that the bad line has an inappropriate/inconsistent amount of indentation for this type of code (per my tab-stop settings).

In atom, if I use the move-line feature to move the bad line up and then back down, the indentation gets fixed -- it will change from tabs to the appropriate amount of spaces. (Or if it was already spaces, but just not the right amount per my tabstop settings, then that would have been fixed.)

How can I create a action + key-binding to make VS Code do this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS Code, extensions provide the necessary per-language logic to do document formatting and for better or worse, VS Code doesn't currently come with an XML formatter extension.

To resolve this:

1. Make sure the Language Mode (bottom right) is set appropriately (in this case, to XML)
2. Select the `Format Document` command from the palette
3. You should get a popup saying `There is no formatter for 'xml-files' installed.` (or something else, if you weren't dealing with XML)
4. Click the "Install Formatter..." button in the popup
5. Install something near the top with a decent star-rating and a lot of downloads (for XML, the "XML" extension by Red Hat would be a great choice)

Now that you have that, you can go back to your document. Make sure the tab-type and tab-size settings are appropriate. Once you've done that, the standard `Move Line Up` / `Move Line Down` commands should reformat indentation as expected.

Comment: That did *not* solve it. I don't want to format the whole document; I just want to move a line. That said, I greatly appreciate the response and will approve if you edit! Your comment led me to search for a "format document" command in the palette, which errored out with a popup that prompted me to install a document formatter from marketplace ... I installed the xml one from Red Hat and then finally was able to use the standard Move-UP/Move-Down commands to get back the functionality I expect.

Comment: I got it! You can move lines with
`(alt) + up/down keys`
Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46775953/10772500

Comment: RE "I got it! You can move lines with (alt) + up/down keys": Yep I know how to move a line. That wasn't my question; I was asking how to make VS Code's move-line feature do proper language-specific auto-indent, like Atom. Again, you pointed me in the right direction by saying "You have to install the necessary document formater extension. and use ctrl+shift+I to format the document" (full content of your original answer), but that doesn't actually answer the question. I'll see if I can edit your answer myself to help out.